# Decompressing tar.zst file-- why am I getting a premature end error?

Tags: compression, zstd, zstandard

I have been trying to download this dataset through my Mac terminal. I know it's huge! https://zenodo.org/record/3606810

I have the tar.zst file, and when I try to decompress (using `zstd -d pol_0616-1119_labeled.tar.zst`), it throws me this error:

`1119_labeled.tar.zst : Read error (39) : premature end`

I've looked like crazy for ways to troubleshoot. Is there something obvious I'm missing? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Maybe the file is corrupted ? A classical issue could be that the end was truncated.
This could be tested using `zstd -t pol_0616-1119_labeled.tar.zst`

Answer (score 7):

The error might be a corrupted file, or a file that wasn't closed properly. Annoyingly in this case zstd gives you nothing. You can work around this by letting zstd output to stdout and redirecting that into a file

```
zstd -d pol_0616-1119_labeled.tar.zst --stdout > pol_0616-1119_labeled.tar
```

This trick gives you as much data as it can successfully decompress